# May Cassandra maps hold null values

Tags: dictionary, null, cassandra

May a Cassandra (CQL 3) `map` hold null values? I thought null values were permitted, but failure of my program suggests otherwise. Or is there a bug in the driver I am using?

The [official documentation for CQL `map`s says](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#map):

> A map is a typed set of key-value pairs, where keys are unique. Furthermore, note that the map are internally sorted by their keys and will thus always be returned in that order.

So the *keys* may not be null (otherwise sorting would be impossible), but there is no mention of a requirement that map *values* are not null.

I have a field that is a `map<timestamp,uuid>`, which I am trying to write to using values in a Java `Map< Date, UUID >`. One of the map values (`UUID`s) is null. This seems to cause a NPE in the Cassandra client code (Cassandra version 1.2.6, called from DataStax Java driver 1.0.1) when marshalling the UUID of the map:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.UUIDGen.decompose(UUIDGen.java:82)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.JdbcUUID.decompose(JdbcUUID.java:55)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UUIDType.decompose(UUIDType.java:187)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UUIDType.decompose(UUIDType.java:43)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.MapType.decompose(MapType.java:122)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.MapType.decompose(MapType.java:29)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.BoundStatement.bind(BoundStatement.java:188)
    at [my method]
```

---

The `UUIDGen.decompose(UUID)` method has no special handling of a null `UUID`, hence the NPE. Contrast with `JdbcBoolean.decompose(Boolean)`, which decomposes a null `Boolean` to an empty byte-buffer. Similarly, `JdbcDate.decompose(Date)` decomposes a null `Date` to an empty byte-buffer.

---

I can produce a similar problem if I have a map holding null integers (using a Java `Map< Date, Integer >` with a null value, for a Cassandra `map<timestamp,int>`), so this problem is not restricted to `uuid` values.

Comment: Well, if they're going to permit nulls, it seems like the data types need to handle them consistently. So I'd say this is a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right, null values are not (yet?) supported inside Maps. I faced this thing before and like you couldn't find relative documentation -- In similar situation I help myself with cqlsh

A small test give you the answer

```
CREATE TABLE map_example (
  id text,
  m map<text, text>,
  PRIMARY KEY ((id))
)
```

try

```
insert into map_example (id, m ) VALUES ( 'a', {'key':null});
```

**> Bad Request: null is not supported inside collections**

HTH, Carlo